# JAXB unmarshalling in detail

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am new to jaxb usage, I am able to marshal a java class with xml annotations to .xml but not able to retrive data while unmarshalling. When I do a sysout on my unmarshalled data, it print the address of the context rather than the actual values. I am not sure as where I go wrong.

```
<collections>
    <collectionclass="testclass">
        <group>
            <header code="T123" type="toys"/>
            <obj1 location="1" shelf="4" />
            <obj2 location="7" shelf="2"  count="3"/>
                <associations>
                    <association type="String" associatedName="train" associatedFieldSize="0"/>
                    <association type="DataLength" associatedName="ship" associatedFieldSize="0"/>
                </associations>
            </obj2>
         </group>
           <collectionclass="testclass">
  </collections>
```

Also I would like to know more about terms like "jaxb context" and "java models/ java model classes" generated on unmarshalling an xml document and how it comes into picture.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

try {

```
    File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    System.out.println(customer);

  } catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: I tried something like this,

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Collections.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
 Collections collectionContext = (Collections) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( new File("TestXml.xml") );
 System.out.println(collectionContext ); 

OUTPUT: com.eaxmple.package.test.Collections@63753b6d

Comment: Looks like you are trying to print the object.You should print the properties in that object,then only you can see the values. System.out.println(customer.name);